# Listening for metamask events with ethers in angular app

Tags: metamask, ethers.js

I'm building an Angular app which connects to various blockchain accounts through metamask.  One of my services connects to MetaMask by obtaining a provider and signer using

```
this.myProvider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
this.mySigner = this.myProvider.getSigner();
```

I would like my service to be aware when the user switches accounts or chains, or signs out of metamask and I am trying to find a way to be informed of those events when they happen.

I see that the object returned to `myProvider` is a Web3Provider, which contains an `addListener` method which takes 2 parameters, an `EventType` and a `Listener` but I can't find any documentation on how to access valid Event Types or how to set up a listener   I assume that these events might provide what I am looking for.  Can somebody point me to an example of how to use these events and listeners?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those events are part of [EIP-1193](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1193) definition of the provider API, they are not part of ethers.js or web3.js if I understand correctly. A nice documentation is also present [here](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/ethereum-provider.html).

So to access them, you need to call directly on `window.ethereum` that is injected by Metamask.

```
window.ethereum.on("accountsChanged", (accounts) => {
/* do what you want here */
})
```

Similarly to watch for chain change :

```
window.ethereum.on("chainChanged", (chainId) => {
/* do what you want here */
/* full refresh is recommended */
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering the same ... I find out as @hroussille, but now, how can i properly use that in an Angular app... That's the question !

EDIT --- I found something !

In the constructor of a service i write something like that :

```
constructor() {
 (window as any).ethereum.on('accountsChanged',(accounts) =>{
   console.log(accounts) 
 })
}
```

And it's working :)

Comment: If you want to set the listeners in a component, suggest you put the code as suggested by @hroussille in ngOnit method of your component.  I'm not positive if this is true, but you may also need to add a teardown method in ngOnDestroy to tear down these listeners to avoid memory leaks.